# Input styling with cross

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a specific style for my inputs, soething like the image bellow:

[image]

Is there anyway to have it like this in my inputs (a word highlighted and then cross sign)?

Comment: Yes. Have you googled it?

Comment: I could not find the correct word to search for, since yesterday I am trying to do that

Comment: Maybe search for form tutorials or clever dropdowns?

Comment: I am looking for the style in CSS, this is an autocomplete script

Comment: Try https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/.